# Pandas/Python Adding a column to the dataframe based on the product of cells in said dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

apologiese for a novice question, I am at the very beginning of my journey

I have a table with the following data:

```
      client_type  quantity  total_spent 
0          Retail      4215    129470.67          
1       Wholesale      5180    159642.33          
Total   -------->      9395    289113.00
```

To this table I would like to add a column "quantity%" that would show me proprtions  of Retail and Wholesale customers

Example:

```
      client_type  quantity  total_spent  quantity%
0          Retail      4215    129470.67  0.4486        
1       Wholesale      5180    159642.33  0.5514
Total   -------->      9395    289113.00  1.0000
```

​
I have tried creating a new column and do maths via df.at[] but it would only  give me a following result:

```
      client_type  quantity  total_spent  quantity%
0          Retail      4215    129470.67  0.4486        
1       Wholesale      5180    159642.33  0.4486
Total   -------->      9395    289113.00  0.4486
```

This made me think that I need to create a for loop to create such column with the data I need.

And so here are the questions

- Are there other alternatives to get the required result without creating a for loop?
- How would I go about approaching said for loop, regardless (for learning process) as I am a bit confused about how to approach it

Comment: You can directly divide the `quantity` column by the total: `df['quantity%'] = df.quantity / df.quantity.at['Total']`

Comment: Thank you @Psidom :) exactly what i needed